# Positive but discontinuous derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on an open interval $I$, with $f' > 0$ on $I$. Can $f'$ be discontinuous at a point of $I$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Try $f(x) = 2x + x^2 \sin(1/x)$ with $f(0)=0$.